# The office-equipment tag's only question was deleted, delete the tag

Tags: support, burninate-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should orphan tags be deleted](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299/should-orphan-tags-be-deleted)

Given that the question was deleted, this leaves the tag dangling with no questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's technically not gone yet: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/200/do-i-need-an-ergonomic-mouse-and-keyboard-to-have-an-ergonomic-work-environmen we could remove the tag from that Q though which would trigger the deletion if you think it's necessary...generally these things work themselves out however.

I don't think the tag is off topic/harmful, but given that the only question it exists on is closed, I wouldn't object if someone edited it away either.