# Should orphan tags be deleted

Tags: feature-request

As I just asked for office-equipment, sometimes:

- A question gets created that has a new tag
- The question gets deleted
- The tag has no other questions associated with it at that time.

Should these orphan tags be cleaned up in the interest of less unused clutter?

Answer (score 5):

[Orphan tags are deleted daily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101262/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-can-i-delete-it/101263#101263) and single-use tags are deleted after 6 months if no other questions are tagged with the tag. There's really no need to do anything in this situation.

The tag is effectively dead once the last question with it has been deleted, though I believe it is visible to those who can see deleted questions. It's not a "real tag" until the question is undeleted (if it ever is) or another question is tagged with it.